# Add to Cart ajax/index/add/uenc error Magento

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento

So Magento "suddenly" gave me this error:

```
POST https://www.samplesite.nl/ajax/index/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cub3ZlcnRyZWt…IyMC5odG1sP19fX1NJRD1VJnN0b3JlPQ,,/product/1383/form_key/f7PMMUeIktiFmSpv/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I haven't added a plugin or something what-so-ever it just suddenly appeared.
So what I understand out of [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/magento-ajax-add-to-cart-button-error) question is, that the link is incorrect.
Unfortunately, I have very little knowledge of Magento. I did not understand how to fix this from [that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/magento-ajax-add-to-cart-button-error) question. 
So how do I fix this? Where is the file located? What code needs to be altered to fix this?
 Or maybe another solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code doesn't just "stop" working, something was changed that caused this to happen.

Comment: @Epodax Hence that I said "suddenly" I have no clue either

Answer (score 0):

Many possibility possible in this case like

- New extension installed
- Already installed extension configuration change
- Theme setting change
- Override add to cart url method

so you have to check one by one case in your magento.
If you still not find the problem then let me know.